# Service now Url authentication

Tags: python, servicenow

I want to access the following service now url without it having to redirect me to the login page. How do I autheticate and follow this url directly? Assume I have the login credentials with me.

https://dev73227.service-now.com/com.glideapp.servicecatalog_cat_item_view.do?v=1&sysparm_id=2ae5d7792fa4401057682ea62799b656&sysparm_preview=true&sysparm_domain_restore=false&sysparm_stack=no

I have tried using web scraping in python but I want achieve this without using scraping. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik this would be possible with https://user:password@servicenow.com but that's not supported by servicenow. There are reasons to not use plain passwords in URLS or Requests before https handshakes.
What do you want to achieve?

Edit: For logging people in via email or link, you can generate a digest token and add this to the URL: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-platform-administration/page/integrate/single-sign-on/concept/c_DigestTokenAuthentication.html

Comment: I need to authorize the end user to access the servicenow instance without him having to type in user name and password while accessing the instance when I provide him with the link. Is that possible?

Comment: Thats exactly what a digest Token is for https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-platform-administration/page/integrate/single-sign-on/concept/c_DigestTokenAuthentication.html